# PHP custom function return value from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

i have looked at the other results for what i'm trying to do, none of them do what i need them to. What i am trying to do is something like this:

```
myfunction(){
    require('./connect.php'); //connect to database
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'"); //user is defined outside the function but it works in my login function which i use the same way.
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $value = row['value'];
        mysql_close();
        return $value;
   } else {
       $errmsg = "connection failed.";
       $value = 0;
       return $value;
   }
}
```

In my php file i would do something like this at the top.

```
$value = myfunction();
```

This does not work.
Ultimately what i'm trying to accomplish is getting a value from the database and output it from the function in another file.
(this is my first post on stackoverflow so if i need to change this feel free to tell me and i shall)

Comment: Okay, the code you posted does return something into $value? have you printed it?

Comment: is there a col named "value" or would you like to return e.g. the col "id"?

Comment: $user is undefined, so you're doing `username=''`, basically.

Comment: Marc $user is defined outside the function then passed to it.
donald123 there is a col named value and it has a number in it. i would like to have that value taken out of the col and displayed to the user.
Marco i have it just outputs 0. even when i have a value set in the database.

Comment: How are you passing $user to the function? Could you include that part perhaps? Because we don't see any parameters. I would suggest you to use the answer of lolka_bolka and add the parameter to it it should work perfectly.

Comment: Sinan in the actual function i am not using a perameter for my login/logout function and it works just fine. but i'll try it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has  several syntax error. Check this, and read my comments:

```
function myfunction() {
    //connect to database
    require('./connect.php');

    //user is defined outside the function but it works in my login function which i use the same way.
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
        return $row['value']; //Missing $ sign
        //No need to create $value if you just return with that.
        //mysql_close();
        //return $value;
    } else {
        //Where do you use this errmsg????
        $errmsg = "connection failed.";
        return 0;
        // These 2 lines are unnecessary.
        //$value = 0;
        //return $value;
    }
} //Missing function close
```

In my example, I've just leave the mysql functions, but please do not use them, they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead. Also, avoid sql injections by escapeing your variables!

Comment: the errmsg variable im echoing at the end for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
$value = row['value']; // <-------- you forgot the $
```

and most probably, the correct way to extract the result is,

```
$row[0]['value'];
```

## Note:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score -1):

i'm thinking you forgot a dot here.

```
require('./connect.php');
```

And a bit of function improvement

```
    myfunction(){
        require_once('../connect.php'); //connect to database
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$user."'"); //user is defined outside the function but it works in my login function which i use the
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows == 1){
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
            $value = $row['value'];
            mysql_close();
        }
        else{
            $errmsg = "connection failed.";
            $value = 0;
        }
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: You forgot a fatal syntax error in your code `row['value']`